# Adjectives with -ing

Tags: adjectives, present-continuous

Does the sentence below use *present continuous*, or is the word "flashing" used as *adjective*?

> The lights on your computer is **flashing**.

Comment: Compare with "Your dog's tail is wagging" or "Your mother is knitting." Do those seem to you to be adjectives?

Answer (score 1):

It is present continuous used incorrect. It should be:

> The light**s** on your computer **are flashing**.

because the "lights" are flashing, not the "computer".

---

From @**JasonBassford** in comments: More importantly, it's not being used as an adjective.

Comment: More importantly, it's not being used as an adjective.